# How do I diagnose gnome-shell crashes

Tags: gnome, crash

I am a long time Xfce usr. For me, it just works. I really want to like Gnome, but for me it crashes all the time. I am talking every 15 minutes or so. Gnome shell will freeze, if I am lucky it will crash and restart if I am not so lucky I have to open a terminal with ctrl-alt-f whatever and restart GDM. (I havn't restarted gnome-shell but I guess that will work also). If I am  really unlucky I have to reboot.

Everything is standard except for a gnome-shell theme and an icon pack. I have a few installed as I really don't like the default theme.

I am running ubuntu 16.04 with gnome-shell 3.18 and I have also tried gnome-shell 3.20 from the staging PPA. The issue is the same with both versions.

So I have 2  questions.

1. Is gnome-shell considered unstable ?
2. How do I pin down the cause of the crashing, will there be some useful info in any logs ?

Thanks for any advice offered.

Comment: Anybody have anything ?